# function get_user_id arrowchat

Tags: php, mysql, get, customization, userid

I try to install `Arrowchat` on my website but don't find `userid`

[image]

the original cod from `Arrowchat` is this

```
/**
     * This function returns the user ID of the logged in user on your site.  Technical support will not
     * help you with this for stand-alone installations.  You must purchase the professional installation
     * if you are having trouble.
     *
     * Suggestion: Check out the other integration files in the functions/integrations directory for
     * many examples of how this can be done.  The easiest way is to get the user ID through a cookie.
     *
     * @return the user ID of the logged in user or NULL if not logged in
     */

    function get_user_id() 
    {

        $userid = NULL;

        if (isset($_COOKIE['userid']))
        {
            $userid = $_COOKIE['userid'];
        }

        return $userid;

    }
```

This is in config.php

```
define('DB_USERTABLE','users'); 
define('DB_USERTABLE_NAME','username'); 
define('DB_USERTABLE_USERID','idu'); 
define('DB_USERTABLE_AVATAR','image');
```

My userid from mysql is `idu`

Comment: on which files ? `index.php` of the website or `integration.php` of arrowchat ? @Fred-ii-

Comment: and this add code must on index.php or integration.php ?

Comment: ok from index.php no error, from integration.php come out this

`ob_start(): output handler 'ob_gzhandler' conflicts with 'zlib output compression' in /home/u276919318/public_html/arrowchat/external.php on line 22

ob_start(): failed to create buffer in /home/u276919318/public_html/arrowchat/external.php on line 22

Array to string conversion in /home/u276919318/public_html/arrowchat/external.php on line 351

Undefined variable: user_avatar in /home/u276919318/public_html/arrowchat/external.php on line 359`